# IBM Websphere MQ Session Lifetime

Tags: ibm-mq

What are the best practices regarding sessions in an application that is designed to fetch messages from a MQ server every 5 seconds?

Should I keep one session open for the whole time (could be weeks or longer), or better open a session, fetch the messages, and then close the session again?

I am using the .net IBM XMS v8 client library.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Attila Repasi's response, I would go for a consumer with message listener attached. The message listener would get called whenever a message needs to be delivered to application. This avoids application explicitly calling receive() to retrieve messages from queue and waste CPU cycles if there are no messages on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the XMS.NET [best practices](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024064)

> Keep the connection and session open for a longer period if your application sends or receive message continuously. Creation of connection or session is a time consuming operation and consumes lot of resources and involves network flow (for client connections).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are calling a session, but typically applications connect to the queue manager serving them once at start, and keep that connection up while running.
I don't see a reason to disconnect just to reconnect 5 seconds later.

As for keeping the queues open, it depends on your environment.
If there are no special circumstances, I would keep the queue open.

I think the most worth thinking about is how you issue the GETs to read the messages.

Comment: A session is a session ;)
What you get when calling:

````ISession session = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge);````